# Hiding lamp in glossy material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have plane with glossy material and point light.

[image]

You can see the white dot in the plane as point light.

[image]

How to retain glossy plane but so that point light is not seen on the plane ?

EDIT: I have tried to modify point lamp material but lamp is still on glassy plane.
[image]

Comment: I changed material of point light but the light is still seen on glossy plane.

Comment: As I look into the question now I don't understand what are you trying to do. If you remove light source visibility from the plane its "glossiness" won't be visible as it's visible because light source is visible in the plane. If you don't remove it then there's no reason to set up anything - light source itself won't be visible to camera as it's a lamp. If you want light source to only lighten up the object and glossy plane to reflect only the background uncheck Glossy in light source settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is the result you are after:

[image: final]

To achieve this you will need to mix **Emission** with **Transparent** (pure white colour- #FFFFFF) shaders in **Lamp** material by **Light** **Path** > **Glossy Depth** as below:

[image: node_setup]

> **Note:** If you change Glossy Roughness (should be 0) even a bit, light will still be visible.